# Exclude functions from Pester code coverage

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

The latest versions of Pester work with a PesterConfiguration object to set the configuration for the unit testing, as described [here](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/commands/New-PesterConfiguration).

In the 'old' command line settings of Invoke-Pester I could utilize a specific setting (Function) for [Code Coverage](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/code-coverage), in which you can include/exclude functions in the to be tested file.

However, this option seems to be missing in the new PesterConfiguration object. I also cannot use both methods together unfortunately.

How can I still exclude functions for code coverage, while keeping the PesterConfiguration?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible to filter by Describe/Context block and expect the CodeCoverage to report coverage for just that function:
https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/2144

You set `PassThru` so that it returns the results of the test:
`$config.Run.PassThru = $true`

In that return object there's `$result.CodeCoverage` - I've used that to dial in on a specific function via:

```
$commandsExecuted = $CodeCoverageReport.CommandsExecuted | Where-Object { $_.Function -eq $FunctionName } | Select-Object -Property Function, StartLine, EndLine, Command
$commandsMissed = $CodeCoverageReport.CommandsMissed | Where-Object { $_.Function -eq $FunctionName } | Select-Object -Property Function, StartLine, EndLine, Command
$percentageOfCommandsExecutedInFunction = ($CommandsExecuted.Count / ($CommandsExecuted.Count + $CommandsMissed.Count)) * 100

$functionCoverage = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'FunctionName' = $FunctionName
    'CommandsExecuted' = $commandsExecuted
    'CommandsMissed' = $commandsMissed
    'CodeCoveragePercentage' = $percentageOfCommandsExecutedInFunction
}
```